# How to trap a return code in a string and rerun

Tags: linux, bash

So My question is I am trying to figure how to read the output from the commands i posted.

So the output pastes a block of text showing the result of the import and in the text it also either says exit code = 0 if it has worked or exit code = 255 if it has not. So i want the string to take that exit code from the text and then depending on the error code it should either re-run the command and try again three times or quit the program if it has worked.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
i="0"
while [ $i -ne 3 ]
do

    string1=$(sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import finance_backup)
    string2=$(sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import finance_deactivate_quotes)
    string3=$(sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import finance)

    if [ "$string1" == "code = 255" ] || [ "$string2" == "code = 255" ] || [ "$string3" == "code = 255" ]
then

    sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import finance_backup
    sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import finance_deactivate_quotes
    sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/full_import.php --import finance
    ((i++))
    sleep 3s
    echo it works
fi
string3="exit code = 0"
echo It works
done
```

Comment: Your problem description is unintelligible, at least for me.

Comment: @ceving i reworded it, should make more sense now|?

Comment: What if only one of the three commands fails? Do you want to re-run all commands until all of them succeed in the same run (or reach the maximum of three runs), or do you only want to re-run the failing commands?

Comment: @socowi I would ideally want all three t o be successful. If one fails then it would indeed run all three again yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Extracting Text

You can use `grep -o` to extract a part of a string. In cases in which you don't care about the extracted string but only about whether that string was found or not you can use `grep -q`:

```
import() {
    sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import "$@"
}

exitCodeIs0() {
    grep -qF 'exit code = 0' <<< "$*"
}

for i in {1..3}; do
    echo "Importing..."
    output1=$(import finance_backup)
    output2=$(import finance_deactivate_quotes)
    output3=$(import finance)
    if exitCodeIs0 "$output1" && exitCodeIs0 "$output2" && exitCodeIs0 "$output3"; then
        echo "Success."
        break
    fi
    echo "Error."
done
```

This won't print the output of the `nginx` commands. If you want to see the output then add `printf %s\\n "$output1" "$output2" "$output3"` in front of the `if`.

### Using The Real Exit Codes

It would be strange if the exit code would only be returned in text form. Most likely you can (and should) use the real exit code rather than extracting it from the textual output:

```
import() {
    sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import "$@"
}

for i in {1..3}; do
    echo "Importing..."
    status=0
    import finance_backup
    (( status += $? ))
    import finance_deactivate_quotes
    (( status += $? ))
    import finance
    (( status += $? ))
    if (( status == 0 )); then
        echo "Success."
        break
    fi
    echo "Error."
done
```

This will print the output of the `nginx` commands. If you don't want to see the output then add `>&-` at the end of the command, directly after the `"$@"`.

### Running Only Failed Commands Again

Up until now we ran all three imports again even if only one of them failed. You said you wanted to do it that way but it seems odd to me. The commands seem to be independent so it would make sense to only run those commands again which failed:

```
import() {
    sudo -u nginx php /var/www/html/shell/global/full_import.php --import "$@"
}
for arg in finance_backup finance_deactivate_quotes finance; do
    for i in {1..3}; do
        if import "$arg"; then
            echo "Success."
            break
        fi
        echo "Error."
    done
done
```